# Using Spork with jasmine in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, jasmine, spork

Since several months, I've used spork with rspec successfuly in a rails app. Now **I try to add jasmine** to this game, so I added to my Gemfile

```
gem 'headless'
gem 'jasmine'
gem 'jasmine-rails'
```

**Jasmine works very well in standalone mode** but it requires to launch firefox for each run which is not very user friendly and I noticed that it is possible to use it with spork. But **when I launch spork** :

```
Using RSpec
Preloading Rails environment
Loading Spork.prefork block...
No runner found, attempting to compile...
make: *** No rule to make target `clean'.  Stop.
which: no gmake in (/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/java/bin:/opt/java/db/bin:/usr/bin/core_perl:/opt/qt/bin:/home/user/.gem/ruby/1.9.1/bin/)
which: no qmake-qt4 in (/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/java/bin:/opt/java/db/bin:/usr/bin/core_perl:/opt/qt/bin:/home/user/.gem/ruby/1.9.1/bin/)
Failure to open file: /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/jasmine-headless-webkit-0.8.4/ext/jasmine-webkit-specrunner/Makefile
Unable to generate makefile for: specrunner.pro
true
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:1371:in `initialize': Permission denied - /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/jasmine-headless-webkit-0.8.4/ext/jasmine-webkit-specrunner/Makefile (Errno::EACCES)
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:1371:in `open'
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:1371:in `block in copy_file'
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:1370:in `open'
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:1370:in `copy_file'
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:477:in `copy_file'
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:396:in `block in cp'
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:1515:in `block in fu_each_src_dest'
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:1531:in `fu_each_src_dest0'
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:1513:in `fu_each_src_dest'
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:395:in `cp'
from extconf.rb:10:in `<main>'
Permission denied - /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/jasmine-headless-webkit-0.8.4/ext/jasmine-webkit-specrunner/jasmine-webkit-specrunner (Errno::EACCES)
```

Any idea to solve this? Is there any other option for having background testing of jasmine?

I use :

- archlinux
- ruby 1.9.3p327
- rails 3.2.8
- spork 0.9.2
- jasmine 1.3.1

Answer (score 1):

There is another way to avoid opening Firefox - PhantomJS . It replaces the Selenium driver , which needs to use Firefox . PhantomJS uses another approach - headless version of WebKit . You can get more useful information taking a look at [this Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/391-testing-javascript-with-phantomjs?view=asciicast) .

Answer (score 1):

What versions are your qmake and qmake-qt4? You can get them by running `qmake-qt4 -v` and `qmake -v`.

Apparently, you need version Qt 4.7 installed for jasmine-headless-webkit. You might have a lower version installed. Check this issue: [No runner found, attempting to compile...](https://github.com/johnbintz/jasmine-headless-webkit/issues/80)

Try upgrading to a newer version of Qt, by referring to notes [here](http://johnbintz.github.com/jasmine-headless-webkit/).

Comment: I have Qmake version 2.01a and Qt 4.8.4 so it does not seems to be related to this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using https://github.com/netzpirat/guard-jasmine.

You will have to eventually install phantomJS (and possibly guard also) but guard-jasmine basically monitors your jasmine specs and whenever there's a change that occurs it will run your tests in the console. It also provides a wrapper to run jasmine in the browser if necessary.